# Android onClickListener without xml

Tags: android, button, onclick, onclicklistener, android-gridlayout

here it is my code:

```
...
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myGrid= (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridlayout);
        myGrid.setColumnCount(3);
        myGrid.setRowCount(5);

        ImageButton a1 = new ImageButton(this);
    ImageButton a2 = new ImageButton(this);
    myGrid.addView(a1);
    myGrid.addView(a2);
    a1.setOnClickListener(this);
    a2.setOnClickListener(this);
...
```

What I need to write in onClick method? I want that if I press button "a1" it will do something and if I press button "a2" it will do something another.

```
public void onClick(View a) {


 I can't use "if (a.getId == buttonID)" , because my buttons haven't ID.
    }
```

In simple Java it was like if((a.getSource() == button1)), but I don't know how it looks in Android.

Comment: You can always have Anonymous Inner Classes as suggested by @Salauyou but its a good practice to have `ID` for your button elements

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I am adding buttons without xml, so i can't have button ID, I'am right?

Comment: You can add `id` for the buttons added dynamically. But thats a different story. Good that you got it solved  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android, you need to override `onClick` method in the listener:

```
a1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view){
       // do something
   }

});
```

Or create a custom listener one for both buttons, where you will check which view was clicked:

```
myOnClickListener = new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        if (view == a1){
           // do what a1 should do
        } else if (view == a2) {
           // do what a2 should do
        }
    }
};
```

and append it to both buttons:

```
a1.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);
a2.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);
```